# Advanced database crawler issue with sitecore 7.2

Tags: lucene, sitecore, lucene.net

I'm new to lucene search in sitecore.I am facing a couple of issues on it.

Does advanced datababse crawler support in Sitecore 7.2?I have downloaded the DLLs from the Nuget and added the configuration file.When i try to rebuild the index,I am getting following issue.

> Could not load file or assembly 'Lucene.Net, Version=2.3.1.3,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

What could be the reason for this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Advanced Database Crawler module is no longer supported or required in Sitecore 7. Instead there is a new built in ContentSearchManager API, you should use this instead.

Start by reading the [Developer’s Guide to Item Buckets and Search](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Reference/Sitecore%207/Developers%20Guide%20to%20Item%20Buckets%20and%20Search.aspx) and [Search and Indexing Guide](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Reference/Sitecore%207/Sitecore%20Search%20and%20Indexing%20Guide.aspx) on SDN and also take a look here for more useful blog posts: http://sitecore-community.github.io/docs/documentation/Search/index.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I have one more doubt.I haven't tried ContentSearchManager.I saw a couple of example in ADC like Search on Date fields,Range,Multi field search etc.Can i achieve the same thing in the ContentSearchManager.Plz share if you know any good reference.Thanks one again.

Comment: You can use the [PredicateBuilder](http://www.sitecore.net/Learn/Blogs/Technical-Blogs/Sitecore-7-Development-Team/Posts/2013/05/Sitecore-7-Predicate-Builder.aspx) to add in your search terms. Anything you were able to do in ADC you can do in with the ContentSearchManager, configuration is much simpler and indexing options are much better. Dig in and ask another question if you get stuck but don't be worried you will be missing anything.

Comment: More [blog posts](http://www.sitecore.net/Learn/Blogs/Technical-Blogs/Sitecore-7-Development-Team/Archive.aspx) from the Sitecore Team and also play with [Autohaus Demo site](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Autohaus.aspx), it is good intro to the  search.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the marketplace states that it does not support Sitecore 7+
  https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/Search_Contrib.aspx?sc_lang=en

The message you get is because Sitecore 7+ uses Lucene 3.0.3 and the module uses 2.3.1.3